# Dispatcher.Invoke appears to be executing async or not executing at all, sometimes

Tags: c#, wpf

I have some network operations going on, and I'm updating some WPF elements throughout the network messaging.

I have a `listbox` of "clients", that I update every time there is a new connection.

So, on connection;

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        listBox.Items.Clear();
    });

        for (i = 0; i < waitingMachines.Count; i++) {
            sb.Clear();
            sb.Append((i + 1).ToString() + ") " + waitingMachines[i].Name + " - " + waitingMachines[i].CurrentMeasurement);
            Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                listBox.Items.Add(sb.ToString());
            });
        }
```

Sometimes it appears that the `listBox.Items.Clear();` does not get executed at all, and I end up with 2 identical entries in the listbox.

If I'm to understand `Invoke`, it should be clearing the list before it can execute the next `Invoke`.. so I'm not sure how I'm getting duplicate entries.

Comment: Why not first create a list or array of item strings, and then do the Clear/Add operations in a single Dispatcher call?

Comment: Crystal ball says that "every time there is a new connection" doesn't actually work and this code is running thousands of times per second.  The very rapid updating of the listbox can create psychedelic effects.  Diagnose by adding Thread.Sleep(100), if it now looks very different then that's the problem.

Comment: @Clemens right... that makes much more sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely that is regular race condition. Since you use `Dispatcher.Invoke`, I assume that code block can be run by multiple threads simultaneously. Then both threads can enter this block and both invoke `listBox.Items.Clear()` one after another. Then they both will add items to the list box and in result you have duplicated items.

In general you should read about bindings and MVVM pattern in WPF, because instead of doing what you do now you could just bind your listbox to array of strings and assign that array in one call, without explicitly invoking dispatcher. This would avoid this race condition.

Comment: Hmm, even if two threads were executing that code at almost the same place at the same time, I still thought it would have executed those in the right order, but I see what you mean. I'll look into a better method of accomplishing this.  Edit: actually never mind, they are executing in the right order, just at unfortunate times.

Comment: If you don't want to use bindings for some reason - use what Clemens proposed in a comment - combine clearing and adding items in a single dispatcher call.

Comment: I'll look into data binding. I imagine that would handle most weird threading situations by itself?